# Parse JSON file in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to parse a JSON file in ansible. I'm able to print the values, but I'm having issues to print the nested values.

This is the JSON file basic structure:

```
{
  "Hosts": [
    {
      "LocNm": "Test",
      "Domain": "",
      "IsVM": "YES",
      "IPAddr": "x.x.x.x",
      "RAM": "2 GB",
      "Apps": [
        {
          "AppOwner": "lala",
          "AppMgDir": "lalal",
          "AppCrit": "Important",
          "AppNm": "MyVacations"
        }
      ],
      "Hostnm": "SomeServer",
      "Environment": "Prod",
      "HWModel": "-",
      "HWManu": "VMware",
      "OSVer": "2008",
      "OSnm": "Windows Server 2008",
      "Cores": 12,
      "OSManu": "Microsoft",
      "SerialNum": ""
    },
     AnotherHost, 
     AnotherHost
}
```

This is the code I'm using in Ansible:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        server_changes: "{{ lookup('file','/opt/playbooks/files/server_changes.json')|from_json }}"

    - name: "Print all App Names"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.Apps.AppNm }}"
      when: item.OSnm is search('Windows') and item.Hostnm == "lalal"
      loop: "{{ flexera_changes.Hosts }}"
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't understand how to get to the Apps Names (AppNm).

I'm always getting:

> TASK [Print all hostnames]***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no
>   attribute 'AppNm'\n\nThe error appears to be in
>   '/opt/playbooks/flexera_esl_integration/flexera_esl_compare.yml': line
>   26, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name:
>   \"Print all hostnames\"\n      ^ here\n"}

I think the problem is when it try to read the [{ and }]?

Thanks

Comment: It does not appear you have posted the actual playbook you are running, for two reasons: there is no task named "Print all hostnames" in your question, and there is no occurrence of the string `value` except in your error message. You have to show us the actual code if you expect an actual answer

Comment: You are correct, I added a different output of one of the test I made. I have updated the question with the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking a `list` for an attribute instead of asking the member of that list for the attribute:

```
- debug:
    # this will give you all AppNm attributes
    msg: "{{ item.Apps | map(attribute='AppNm') | list }}"
  loop: "{{ flexera_changes.Hosts }}"

- debug:
    # this will give you just the first one, if you are
    # 100% confident there will always be exactly one
    msg: "{{ item.Apps[0].AppNm }}"
  loop: "{{ flexera_changes.Hosts }}"
```